# phrases that work as verb or verbal phrases working as adjective?

Tags: parsing

In the example:

1 - "The most beautiful and perfect experiences of my life all happened when I was trippin' balls."

I belive "trippin' balls" is a reference to some thing being used to ilustrate a state someone is at.

Question one: is "trippin' balls" a phrase being used like a verb or an adjective here?

example 2:

2 - " I smoked some amazing bud and got ripped off my ass when I was supposed to be helping Jenna with her homework."

if we isolate "ripped off my ass" from the text it seems like ripped is a verb so "ripped off my ass" would be more like a verb phrase right?

question two: is "ripped off my ass" in this example being used like an adjective?

Comment: I'd never seen ***trippin' balls*** before, but it looks to me as if it derives from ***tripping = under the influence of LSD or other psychotropic drugs***, and ***balls*** is just a quirky "adverbial intensifier" (cf ***intensely, like crazy***). But *syntactically speaking*, the two-word term ***trippin' balls*** here is no different to any ordinary adjective, as in *...it all happened when I was **young***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers would you say the same goes for example number 2?

Comment: "ripped off my ass" (or plain "ripped", the additional adverbial element is syntactically irrelevant) just *happens* to feature a past tense verb being used ***adjectivally***. For another past tense verb that could be used there instead, consider *I bought some amazing beer and **got drunk**...* Note that the fact that these are past tense verbs is a bit irrelevant once we consider how they're being used *(**adjectivally**)*.

Comment: Consider *I bought some expensive beer and got **upset** when I realised it was a low-alcohol drink*. Strictly speaking, even there, ***upset*** is a past tense noun used adjectivally. If we change it to an *ordinary* (non-verb-based) adjective, such as *I bought some expensive beer and got **happy** when I realised it contained a mescaline-soaked worm as powerful as a tab of acid,* most native speakers wouldn't like ***got + happy*** at all (even supposing they didn't object to the *meaning* of my quirky example! :)